# How to create nested JSON based on array of keys?

Tags: javascript

Given input:

```
let input = [
  {
    schema: ["user", "email"],
    value: "test@test.com"
  },
  {
    schema: ["user", "name", "firstName"],
    value: "John"
  },
];

let output = {};

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    let data = input[i];

    for (let j = 0; j < data.schema.length; j++) {
        let s = data.schema[j];
        // How to set nested levels here ? eg: output["user"]["email"] = {};
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "user": {
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "name": { 
            "firstName": "John" 
        }
    }
}
```

Here "schema" represents the nested structure in JSON for the data.

What is the approach for dynamically setting nested attributes using Javascript ?

Comment: What is `data.schema`? What about `output["user"]["email"] = {};` isn’t working?

Comment: @Xufox : I cannot use output["user"]["email"] since "user" and "email" will be dynamic.

Comment: Okay, then just replace `"user"` and `"email"` with the variables containing the dynamic strings. See [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2274242/4642212).

Comment: It is represented as array eg: ["user", "email"] so I will need to loop to set it. 
Please refer to the example, I have updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `reduce` to "deepen" the output object until the level where the property/value needs to be set:

```js
const input = [{schema: ["user", "email"],value: "test@test.com"},{schema: ["user", "name", "firstName"],value: "John"},];
const output = {};

for (const obj of input) {
    obj.schema.slice(0, -1).reduce(
        (acc, lvl) => acc[lvl] || (acc[lvl] = {}), 
        output
    )[obj.schema.slice(-1)[0]] = obj.value;
}

console.log(output);
```

This way it also works if the schema array has more than 2 values.

Comment: The OP has changed the question's body!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Adapted the input in my answer accordingly.

Comment: Works flawlessly, Thank you :)